# Something similar to ASP.NET WebAPI in Java

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for the same (or, at least, very similar) tool like ASP.NET WebAPI (C#) in Java world, so I can use it with the JavaScript $.ajax call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest is [*Java API for RESTful Web Services*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services):

> JAX-RS: Java API for RESTful Web Services is a Java programming language API that provides support in creating web services according to the Representational State Transfer (REST) architectural pattern. JAX-RS uses annotations, introduced in Java SE 5, to simplify the development and deployment of web service clients and endpoints.

See full examples in the [*JAX-RS Tutorial - Mkyong.com*](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/) and [*JAX-RS - YouTube*](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=JAX-RS&search_sort=video_view_count).